# Case Statement for needing to select one or multiple answers in a column

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, case, reportbuilder3.0

I need a Case Statement where I can choose the answers depending on if the Answer column has a NULL value or not.

For example if one of the rows has a NULL in Answer, i would only choose the names showing up that is not Null.  And would like it to display like "Clark Kent And Lois Lane".

If there was just one name in the Answer column then i would like it just show "Clark Kent"

| QuestionID | EncounterID | Answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1636 | 1234 | Clark Kent |
| 1637 | 1234 | NULL |
| 1638 | 1234 | Lois Lane |

Comment: Will the NULL value always be in the middle of two records that have a value? and you would like to combine the two answers from the top and bottom records?

Comment: What's the expected result of the table contains thousands of rows?

Comment: @GRIV no the NULL value will not always be in the middle.  I could have just one name listed and 2 NULL values.  or I could have first 2 rows with names and last row be a NULL value.  so basically just want the names.  If its its multiple names i would like Name 1 And Name 2 And Name 3, or Name 2 and Name 3, or Name 1 only.

Comment: @jarlh table will only have 2-3 rows max.  so just wanted to have data of only the name/s

Comment: So there may be many names, how would you group those names together if you don't have a key? QuestionId and EncounterId aren't unique. So basically, how would you know what names to place in the NULL values?

Comment: @GRIV apologies.  the encounterID would be the same in that table.  so they would be grouped by that.  I edited my question to show that.

Comment: What if the Answer column had two rows with the same EncounterID, so NULL and Clark Kent, would you like to see Clark Kent and Clark Kent (twice - one for each QuestionID) or remove the NULL QuestionID completely in this case?

Comment: @GRIV i would like to remove the row with the NULL value.  so if there was a NULL value in the Answer column, then i would not want to include that row.  Only output i would like is just the names in the Answer column.  so if only 1 name, than i want that, if 2 or 3 then, then show the 2 or 3 names.

Comment: @PatStarks333 Understood, I think my concern is around two rows with the same EncounterID as I mentioned above (One NULL, the other with a name so the name would show twice). Please see my answer below, I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for, let me know under my answer on how I can improve it if need be.

Comment: @PatStarks333 I've updated my answer to include scenarios where the name is duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query:

```
select t.EncounterID, 
STUFF((
SELECT (' and ' +  isnull([Answer],'') ) ) 
FROM [TableName] t2
where t2.EncounterID=t.EncounterID  
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 4, '')
from [TableName] t
group by t.EncounterID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `STRING_AGG` within a `CTE`, then `RIGHT JOIN` the `CTE` to your `table` and use a `CASE` statement to check for `NULL` values, replacing it with the `STRING_AGG` result from the `CTE` like this:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT a.EncounterID, 
                    STRING_AGG(a.Answer, ' and ') AS Concat_Column
            FROM sample_table a
             GROUP BY a.EncounterID)
SELECT  
  c.QuestionID,
  c.EncounterID,
  CASE WHEN c.Answer IS NULL THEN d.Concat_Column
       ELSE c.Answer
  END AS Answer
  FROM cte d
  RIGHT JOIN sample_table c ON d.EncounterID = c.EncounterID AND c.Answer IS NULL
```

Optionally, you can use a subquery to get the same result:

```
SELECT c.QuestionID,
       c.EncounterID, 
       CASE WHEN c.Answer IS NULL THEN b.Answer
              ELSE c.Answer
         END AS Answer
FROM sample_table c 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT a.EncounterID, 
                  STRING_AGG(a.Answer, ' and ') AS Answer
           FROM sample_table a
           GROUP BY a.EncounterID) b
           ON b.EncounterID = c.EncounterID AND c.Answer IS NULL
```

**Input:**

| QuestionID | EncounterID | Answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1636 | 1234 | Clark Kent |
| 1637 | 1234 | Lois Lane |
| 1638 | 1234 | null |
| 1639 | 1235 | null |
| 1640 | 1235 | Lex Luthor |
| 1641 | 1235 | null |
| 1642 | 1236 | General Zod |
| 1643 | 1237 | Perry White |
| 1644 | 1237 | null |
| 1645 | 1238 | Jimmy Olsen |
| 1646 | 1239 | Superman |
| 1647 | 1239 | Lana Lang |
| 1648 | 1239 | null |
| 1649 | 1239 | null |

**Output:**

| QuestionID | EncounterID | Answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1636 | 1234 | Clark Kent |
| 1637 | 1234 | Lois Lane |
| 1638 | 1234 | Clark Kent and Lois Lane |
| 1639 | 1235 | Lex Luthor |
| 1640 | 1235 | Lex Luthor |
| 1641 | 1235 | Lex Luthor |
| 1642 | 1236 | General Zod |
| 1643 | 1237 | Perry White |
| 1644 | 1237 | Perry White |
| 1645 | 1238 | Jimmy Olsen |
| 1646 | 1239 | Superman |
| 1647 | 1239 | Lana Lang |
| 1648 | 1239 | Superman and Lana Lang |
| 1649 | 1239 | Superman and Lana Lang |

db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/oRogfPRZ).

Also, if you want to remove the **duplicate** names (which would also remove unique `QuestionID`'s) you can add the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to the outer `SELECT` statement which will assign a sequential integer based on the `EncounterID` column and the `Answer` column from the `STRING_AGG` function. Then, wrap the outer query in parentheses to create another subquery, selecting only values `WHERE` row number = 1 to get the distinct `Answer` rows.

```
SELECT d.QuestionID,
       d.EncounterID,
       d.Answer
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.EncounterID, 
                CASE WHEN c.Answer IS NULL THEN b.Answer 
                     ELSE c.Answer 
                END ORDER BY c.EncounterID) as rn,
             c.QuestionID,
             c.EncounterID, 
             CASE WHEN c.Answer IS NULL THEN b.Answer
                  ELSE c.Answer
             END AS Answer
       FROM sample_table c 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT a.EncounterID, 
                         STRING_AGG(a.Answer, ' and ') AS Answer
                  FROM sample_table a
                  GROUP BY a.EncounterID) b
                  ON b.EncounterID = c.EncounterID AND c.Answer IS NULL) d
WHERE d.rn = 1
```

**Output:**

| QuestionID | EncounterID | Answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1636 | 1234 | Clark Kent |
| 1638 | 1234 | Clark Kent and Lois Lane |
| 1637 | 1234 | Lois Lane |
| 1639 | 1235 | Lex Luthor |
| 1642 | 1236 | General Zod |
| 1643 | 1237 | Perry White |
| 1645 | 1238 | Jimmy Olsen |
| 1647 | 1239 | Lana Lang |
| 1646 | 1239 | Superman |
| 1648 | 1239 | Superman and Lana Lang |

db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/CQDOs8tw).